# How to use reformulate in R when variables have embedded spaces

Tags: r

What is the proper string parsing required to use `reformulate()` when the termlabels have embedded spaces?

This works:

```
reformulate(c("A", "B"), "Y")
Y ~ A + B
```

These all fail:

```
reformulate(c("A var", "B"), "Y")
reformulate(quote(c("A var", "B")), "Y")
reformulate(as.formula(quote(c("A var", "B"))), "Y")
```

Expected results:

```
Y ~ `A var` + B
# or 
Y ~ `A var` + `B`
```

**NOTE**
*I cannot hard code the backticks. This is part of a larger shiny application, therefore, if backticks are the answer, I need a method to do this programmatically.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few other ways that work with symbols rather than strings (so no need for explicit backticks).

```
input <- "A var"
eval(bquote( Y ~ .(as.name(input)) + B))
# Y ~ `A var` + B

eval(substitute( Y ~ INPUT + B, list(INPUT = as.name(input))))
# Y ~ `A var` + B

library(rlang)
eval(expr(Y ~ !!sym(input) + B))
# Y ~ `A var` + B
```

Comment: Thank you for the full coverage. I stumbled upon as.name but couldn't quite get it to cooperate.

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks, e.g.

```
reformulate(c("`A var`", "B"), "Y")
#Y ~ `A var` + B
```

Or better yet, don't use spaces in variable names.

Or with a helper function

```
bt <- function(x) sprintf("`%s`", x)
reformulate(c(bt(var1), var2), "Y")
#Y ~ `A var` + B
```

Comment: Thank you, but I should have been more clear. How can I dynamically or programmatically add the backticks? More context, this part of a larger shiny app -- the spaces are for some UI elements for readability for the user.

Comment: ``input2 <- paste0("`",input,"`")``

Comment: Thanks @Moody_Mudskipper, went down the same path:-)